# Dracaena plant has less leaves

Tags: houseplants, growth

I had planted a Dracaena plant few years back. Since then it has grown tall. The only problem is it has leaves only at the top. I have kept it near my window, so it gets proper sunlight. I water it whenever top layer is dry. Occasionally apply fertilizer also spray water on the leaves. My pot is of medium sized and I have not changed the soil since it was planted. Please advise how to get more leaves.

Comment: can you add a picture please?

Answer (score 2):

I have had dracaena for many years. My experience is that the leaves live 3 or 4 years and then yellow and die. To get leaves lower , I plant a short cutting in the pot.